# Text Fields in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Regbutton.js

```
window.onload = timeout();
//document.getElementById('regButton').onClick = textfield();
function textfield () {
    var x = document.createElement('INPUT'); // INPUT also works
    x.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    x.setAttribute('value', 'text');
}

function timeout(){
    console.log("Loading");
    var button = document.getElementById('regButton');
    if(button != null){
        console.log(button);
    }else{
        console.log("No button");
    }
}
```

popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="regbutton.js"></script>
        <script src="background.js"></script>
    <--...-->

    <button id="regButton" class="button" type="button">Regulations</button>
```

So I am trying to make a textfield on the button click, but it is not working, ideas?

Comment: Where are trying to add the textfield??

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the created element to the document.

```
function textfield() {
    var x = document.createElement('INPUT'); // INPUT also works
    x.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    x.setAttribute('value', 'text');
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
```

Here is a fiddle with a working solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/7gbq9yuo/